# Starting with Chrome 63, urls containing app redirects to https

Tags: google-chrome

Starting with the latest version of Chrome (63), Chrome redirects an internal app with the following url : http://app/ to the https version which does not exist.

After several tries on IIS (there's no SSL binding), it seems to be related to the fact that the url contains the word "app". If i change the url, or if i access the web application with the name of the server, everything works as usual.

Any ideas about this problem ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be due to a new policy in Chrome 63 where Google enforces https on all the TLDs that they own (.app is a Google property)

You can see the list of affected domains https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/master/http/transport_security_state_static.json#285